# Django REST Framework: 'BasePermissionMetaclass' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Python/Django n00b moving over from javascript.

Trying to add an API endpoint using Django REST Framework which I'm hoping will ultimately be able to update a User with the body of a PATCH request, but for now I just want it to not throw a 500 error.

I've added this to urlpatterns:

```
url(r'update/$', views.UpdateView.as_view(), name="update_user"),
```

And that should bring in this view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.generics import UpdateAPIView
from .serializers import UserSerializer

class UpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

The UserSerializer looks like this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'pk', 'status')
```

Seem to be getting this every time I visit the route:

```
TypeError at /api/update/
'BasePermissionMetaclass' object is not iterable
```

I have no idea what I'm doing - anyone seen this before?

UPDATE: Full Traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/update/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "path/to/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "path/to/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "path/to/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "path/to/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "path/to/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "path/to/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "path/to/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
    self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "path/to/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 401, in initial
    self.check_permissions(request)
  File "path/to/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 333, in check_permissions
    for permission in self.get_permissions():
  File "path/to/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 280, in get_permissions
    return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]
TypeError: 'BasePermissionMetaclass' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Show the full traceback.

Comment: Most likely, you defined a permission (either for the class or through settings) and didn't add it as list

Comment: Show the `PERMISSION_CLASSES` config from settings module.

Comment: @SachinKukreja - you mean this?


~~~~
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
       'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
   ),
   'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser'
   ),
}
~~~~

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You have mistyped the comma in `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` value, due to which Django takes it as a string, instead of a tuple.

**Solution**:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   ...
   'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ( 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser', ),
   ...
}
```

Comment: Wow - that was it! Thank you so much - been stuck on this for a couple of days now - such a simple solution!

Comment: Amazing answer!! Thanks!

Answer (score 56):

I had the same problem, but looked for wrong place. I made mixin class with permissions and there was code

```
permission_classes = (
    permissions.IsAuthenticated
)
```

but should be

```
permission_classes = (
    permissions.IsAuthenticated,
#                              ^
#                         a comma here
)
```

So do not forget to look for other classes with permissions. I hope it will help someone.

Comment: for anyone wondering what the change is, you have to add a comma after permissions.IsAuthenticated..it took me few minutes to figure out :)

Comment: idk why it took me 15mins to realize that this comment even exists...

Answer (score 11):

As a reference for other people who might be searching here, this could be an issue too..

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.generics import UpdateAPIView
from .serializers import UserSerializer

class UpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = IsAuthenticated
```

Should change to:

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from rest_framework.generics import UpdateAPIView
    from .serializers import UserSerializer

    class UpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer_class = UserSerializer
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
```

You have to ensure the **comma**

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem and I was able to solve with this simple step

```
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
```

so yeah, just put the method under the permission module in a bracket and you are good to go, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

As an add up, should incase, anyone is following the tutorials on **Django for APIs by William S. Vincent**, the chapter on documentation using **drf-spectacular**, shows similar error stack.

And the solution as illustrated earlier is to put **[ ]** on the custom base permission **IsAuthorOrReadOnly**, as this **[IsAuthorOrReadOnly]**, in the **posts app views**, and the error is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Junst in case [this](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/491) also can be solution. At least solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete @ihafurr's answer.

`permission_classes` shall be iterable because the variable is called by :func:`viewsets.ModelViewSet.get_permission` being (https://www.cdrf.co/3.12/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html):

```
def get_permissions(self):
    return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]
```

Changing the last line of such method to the following could overcome the iterability requirement.

```
return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes] if isinstance(self.permission_classes], Iterable) else [self.permission_classes]
```

where `Iterable` comes from

```
try:
    from collections.abc import Iterable  # for Python >= 3.6
except ImportError:
    from collections import Iterable
```