# Getting error "'list' object is not callable" for authentication_classes

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-viewsets

I have following method:

```
class AbcViewSet(viwesets.ModelViewSet):

    @action(detail=False, permission_classes=(IsOwnerOrReadOnly,))
    @debugger_queries
    def get_xyz(self, request, pk=None):
        # ...
```

Inside this method, `request.user` was always `AnonymousUser`. I felt that it was because I did not specify any kind of authentication for this method.  I skipped through  codebase and found other developers using decorator. So, I tried by adding a decorator `@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication,])` as follows:

```
class AbcViewSet(viwesets.ModelViewSet):

    @action(detail=False, permission_classes=(IsOwnerOrReadOnly,))
    @debugger_queries
    @authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication,])
    def get_xyz(self, request, pk=None):
        # ...
```

But it started me giving `'list' object is not callable` error on this newly added line. I was expecting it to work as we can see similar code here: [1](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/992), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56526740/must-i-include-authentication-classes-attribute-in-my-django-class-view). Django doc too state it [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api-policy-decorators).

Is it that they are used with function based views and are not allowed with View sets? What I am missing here?

**PS**:

My settings.py does have `TokenAuthentication` specified:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    # ...

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),

    # ...
}
```

**PS2:** I also tried following, though its somewhat unrelated to the error:

```
@authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication))
```

and

```
@authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication,))
```

Comment: please follow documentation https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Answer (score 0):

The [doc says](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme):

> You can also set the authentication scheme on a per-view or per-viewset basis, using the `APIView` class-based views.
>
> ```
>  authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
> ```

So I added it as class variable:

```
class AbcViewSet(viwesets.ModelViewSet):

    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication]  # <<=====

    @action(detail=False, permission_classes=(IsOwnerOrReadOnly,))
    @debugger_queries
    def get_xyz(self, request, pk=None):
        # ...
```

And the error is gone.

It was my lack of knowledge that I should not be using `@authentication_classes` decorator in view set, instead define the `authentication_classes` variable in the class.